# Replace line names with set of new names without disturbing the rest of the file

Tags: text-processing

I have a large protein sequence file where each sequence name is identified using `>` and the corresponding sequence in the following lines.

Example (ignore quotation marks):

```
>YAL003W EFB1 SGDID:S000000003, Chr I from 142174-142253,142620-143160, Genome Release 64-1-1, Verified ORF, "Translation elongation factor 1 beta; stimulates nucleotide exchange to regenerate EF-1 alpha-GTP for the next elongation cycle; part of the EF-1 complex, which facilitates binding of aminoacyl-tRNA to the ribosomal A site"
MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
```

I want to remove the majority of the name text to only look like this (ignore quotation marks):

```
>YAL003W EFB1
MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
FDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
```

The names only count as one line whilst the sequences count as multiple, hence my problem. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk solution

```
$ awk '/>/ { print $1, $2; next } { print }' aa
>YAL003W EFB1
MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
```

- />/ search for a > in a line
- next ; do not read any further pattern in awk file

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few solutions:

1. `grep`. The pattern searches for lines that begin with either `>` followed by 2 sequences of non-spaces (`[^ ]+ [^ ]+`) or any characters (`.+`). The `-o` cause `grep` to only print the matched part of each line:

   ```
   $ grep -oP '^(>[^ ]+ [^ ]+|.+)' file.fa 
   >YAL003W EFB1
   MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
   EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
   SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
   LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
   ```
2. `awk`

   ```
   $ awk '{if(/>/){print $1,$2}else{print}}' file.fa 
   >YAL003W EFB1
   MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
   EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
   SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
   LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
   ```
3. GNU `sed`

   ```
   $ sed -r 's/(>[^ ]+ [^ ]+).*/\1/' file.fa 
   >YAL003W EFB1
   MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
   EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
   SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
   LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
   ```
4. Any `sed`

   ```
   $ sed 's/\(>[^ ]* [^ ]*\).*/\1/' file.fa 
   >YAL003W EFB1
   MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
   EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
   SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
   LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
   ```
5. `cut`

   ```
   $ cut -d ' ' -f 1,2 file.fa 
   >YAL003W EFB1
   MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD
   EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK
   SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS
   LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
   ```
6. Perl.

   ```
   $ perl -lane 'print "@F[0..1]"' file.fa 
   >YAL003W EFB1
   MASTDFSKIETLKQLNASLADKSYIEGTAVSQADVTVFKAFQSAYPEFSRWFNHIASKAD 
   EFDSFPAASAAAAEEEEDDDVDLFGSDDEEADAEAEKLKAERIAAYNAKKAAKPAKPAAK 
   SIVTLDVKPWDDETNLEEMVANVKAIEMEGLTWGAHQFIPIGFGIKKLQINCVVEDDKVS 
   LDDLQQSIEEDEDHVQSTDIAAMQKL*
   ```

   The options are

   - `l` : remove trailing newlines from each input line and add a newline to each print call.
   - `a` : split each input line at whitespace into the `@F` array.
   - `n` : read the input file line by line.
   - `e` : run this script on each line.

   The script itself simply prints the 1st and 2nd fields. In the case of the sequence lines, it will just print the only field available, the first. which is the whole line.

Comment: Thanks mate! I feel rather dumb not realising cut would ignore the sequences